# SQL Server 2008 view is losing the default value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I have a strange issue, after some time after a view is created, the default value for applicationID is lost or reset (we don't know why, we had something like 0.000 or 0 or null).

```
CREATE VIEW [schemaA].[tableA]
AS
    SELECT 
        *, 123456 applicationID
    FROM 
        [schemaB].[dbo].[tableA]
```

If we run an `ALTER` statement, the value of `applicationID` returns back to the originally defined value.

```
ALTER VIEW [schemaA].[tableA]
AS
    SELECT 
        *, 123456 applicationID
    FROM 
        [schemaB].[dbo].[tableA]
```

I need to mention that before running the `ALTER` statement, we exported the view DDL and it was correct.

How can I identify what is corrupting the view definition or if the view should have a different definition (maybe set a default value if it's possible).

Thank you

Comment: Is this `applicationID` a literal (fixed) value in any cases? Is your `CREATE VIEW`statememt exactly as above?  If not, please post the full statement.

Comment: @Shnugo the value is fixed upon creation and the statement above is exactly the same

Comment: What does "fixed upon creation" mean exactly? Is this statement recreated by some kind of dynamic process? Or is it created once and never changed?

Comment: @Shnugo it's created once

Comment: Did you try to let SSMS create an ALTER statment for you at the moment your VIEW came back with the wron result? How is this view used? Could it be, that the result is correct, but the caller makes a mistake?

Comment: The ALTER statement was written by hand. Before running it, I selected the values as usual, I noticed that applicationID was wrong and had to update it. I need to mention again that the exported DDL view was correct! My questions is what might be corrupting the view ....

Comment: Probably someone altered table structure (added some fields) and forgot to recompile the view - in that case SQL server screws up the view results, if view definition contains `select *`, not explicit fields list.

Comment: @Arvo, according to your comment I made the example in my answer more specific. In fact this would even muddle up the type... Good reason against the `SELECT *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE testTbl(aColumn INT);
INSERT INTO testTbl VALUES(1),(2);
GO

CREATE VIEW vwTestTbl
AS
SELECT *,1234 applicationID
FROM testTbl;
GO

SELECT * FROM vwTestTbl;
/*
aColumn applicationID
    1   1234
    2   1234
*/
GO

--be aware of the fact, that the new column is called newColumn and its type is varchar(5)!
ALTER TABLE testTbl ADD newColumn varchar(5);
GO
UPDATE testTbl SET newColumn='test';
GO

--The varchar value "test" comes under the column caption "applicationID"!
SELECT * FROM vwTestTbl;
/*
aColumn applicationID
    1   test
    2   test
*/
GO

--now you re-compile it with your attempt to ALTER the VIEW
ALTER VIEW vwTestTbl
AS
SELECT *,1234 applicationID
FROM testTbl;
GO

SELECT * FROM vwTestTbl;
/*
aColumn newColumn applicationID
    1   test      1234
    2   test      1234
*/
GO

--clean up
DROP VIEW vwTestTbl;
DROP TABLE testTbl;
```

Comment: in theory it might, I don't know who might be running "ALTER TABLE testTbl ADD applicationID INT NULL;" , if so, how can I find out?

Comment: @christi_b, without knowing your processes I cannot tell you... Each object has a `modify_date` (Try a `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name='someName'`You'll at least find, when an object was altered the last time...

Comment: it seems that this is the most plausible case